# Concatenating numpy vector and matrix horizontally

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have the following numpy vector `m` and matrix `n`

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([360., 130., 1.])
n = np.array([[60., 90., 120.], 
              [30., 120., 90.],
              [1.,  1.,   1. ]])
```

What I want to do is to concatenate them horizontally resulting in

```
np.array([[60., 90., 120.,360.], 
          [30., 120., 90., 130.],
          [1.,  1.,   1., 1. ]])
```

What's the way to do it?

I tried this but failed:

```
np.concatenate(n,m.T,axis=1)
```

Comment: What about 'np.concatenate(n,m.reshape((1,-1)))' ?

Comment: This is what `column_stack` is for: `np.column_stack([n, m])`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> np.hstack((n,np.array([m]).T))
array([[  60.,   90.,  120.,  360.],
       [  30.,  120.,   90.,  130.],
       [   1.,    1.,    1.,    1.]])
```

The issue is that since `m` has only one dimension, its transpose is still the same. You need to make it have shape (1,3) instead of (3,) before you take the transpose.

A much better way to do this is `np.hstack((n,m[:,None]))` as suggested by DSM in the comments.

Comment: You can use `m[:,None]` instead of `np.array([m]).T` to bump up the dimension.

Comment: This use of `hstack` is, in effect, `np.concatenate((n, m[:,None]), axis=1)`

Answer (score 3):

one way to achieve the target is by converting `m` to a `list` of `list`

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([360., 130., 1.])
n = np.array([[60., 90., 120.],
              [30., 120., 90.],
              [1.,  1.,   1. ]])
m = [[x] for x in m]
print np.append(n, m, axis=1)
```

Another way is to use `np.c_`,

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([360., 130., 1.])
n = np.array([[60., 90., 120.],
              [30., 120., 90.],
              [1.,  1.,   1. ]])
print np.c_[n,m]
```

Comment: Nice use of `c_`.  We don't see that used much.  But fundamentally it is syntatic sugar for `concatenate`.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do `np.column_stack((n, m))`.